# Case when statement in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, case

I have a query right now that merges two queries into one by joining them.  The code for this query is:

```
Select TOP 1 * 
from Media
  join  (SELECT convert(date,
  DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)))) [Date],
  convert(varchar(8), convert(time,
  DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))))) [Time],
  [Object] AS [Dataset],
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media]
  FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
  [Object],
  MsgId,
  Parms
  FROM JnlDataSection) A
  Where MsgID = '325' AND
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) = 'V40449' ) b on Media.SerialNum = b.Media order by Date Desc, Time Desc;
```

I have added the Case When clause into this query:

```
              Select TOP 1 * from Media
  join  (SELECT convert(date,
  DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)))) [Date],
  convert(varchar(8), convert(time,
  DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
    SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
    SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))))) [Time],
    CASE WHEN SiteId = '2' THEN 'IM'
    WHEN SiteId ='3' THEN 'Recall'
    WHEN SiteId ='4' THEN 'SM'
    WHEN SiteId ='5' THEN 'VB'
    WHEN SiteId ='6' THEN 'WM'
    WHEN SiteId ='7' THEN 'IM - F'
    WHEN SiteId ='8' THEN 'IM - C'
    ELSE '' --Optional ELSE
    END AS [Location],
  [Object] AS [Dataset],
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media]
  FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
  [Object],
  MsgId,
  Parms
  FROM JnlDataSection) A
  Where MsgID = '325' AND
  SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) = 'V40449' ) b on Media.SerialNum = b.Media order by Date Desc, Time Desc;
```

However when I run this query it gives me this error:

END AS [Location],

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   FROM JnlDataSection) A
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

I was wondering if anyone can edit my second query so it can run error free with the `Case` clause?

That would be greatly appreciated.  Also please note that the `SiteId` is present only in the Media column. Also I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Would not the relationship that describes `SiteId ='4' THEN 'SM'` et al be better in a table to which you join

Comment: you are using SSMS 2008, is the DBMS 2008 too?

Comment: Strange, when I parse I don't any error... has the database compatibility level 10? 10.5?

Comment: @LuisLL How would I check that?

Comment: to see the database compatibility level see answer below